# How to delete a UITableView Cell when i press a accessoryType delete button?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have just a UItableview. Every cell has a accessoryType symbol(>) in the right of a cell and when i touch a tableview cell it push me a new Viewcontroller. Its simple.

Now problem is that, I want in my tableview cell, when i TouchDragInside the accessoryType symbol it will show me a accessory button(Just like delete Button). When i press the delete button. It will delete the cell from the tableview.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement these two delegate..

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

}
```

// Override to support editing the table view.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
    NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:objects withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];   
    }   
}
```

Hope this will work for you..

Comment: This two TableView delegate functions are not called. Don't know why this happening. Any idea why this two delegate functions are not called.